# python cryptography can't installed on RHEL 8.6 when python version is 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, rhel

we have tried to install the `cryptography` module on our RHEL 8.6 linux machine but without success

here short details about our server

```
pip3 --version
pip 23.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

python3 --version
Python 3.9.16
pip3 list | grep setuptools
setuptools     68.2.2

more /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)

 uname -a
 4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 15 22:12:19 EDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and examples from installation proccess

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --no-index "/tmp/1/cryptography-41.0.4-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl"
ERROR: cryptography-41.0.4-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

and with diff version

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --no-index "/tmp/cryptography-37.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl"
ERROR: cryptography-37.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

or different version

```
 pip3 install --no-cache-dir --no-index "/tmp/cryptography-37.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl"
ERROR: cryptography-37.0.2-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

or

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --no-index "/tmp/cryptography-37.0.3-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl"
ERROR: cryptography-37.0.3-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

or

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir --no-index "/tmp/cryptography-41.0.4.tar.gz"
Processing /tmp/cryptography-41.0.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=61.0.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=61.0.0
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I also downgrade the setuptools to version 38.4.0 but the same error and we reinstall the setuptools to original version - 68.2.2

so we not understand if cryptography cant installed on RHEL 8.6 version with python 3.9

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `uname -a` ? This looks like an architecture issue, you are repeatedly trying to install the x86_64 version of the package. It might be that, the server you are trying this might be using some arm architecture.

Comment: I upload the details in my question

Comment: This is one reason why people use virtual environments

Comment: `pp39-pypy39_pp73` means wheels for PyPy, not for regular Python that you use. It seems `cryptography` doesn't provide wheels for regular python on Linux beyond Python 3.7 so you should [install from sources](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux).

Comment: @wander95 unfortunately we cant use Venv

Comment: @phd can you explain how to install it from source?

Comment: I provided a link to the docs. Not very detailed docs, I must say, but the main points are covered: you need C and Rust compilers, and headers for essential libraries.

Comment: C and Rust compilers are too much installation progress and all this just to install the module , what we need is short way

Comment: do you mean to install the apk and then installing gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo pkgconfig   ?

Comment: "*C and Rust compilers are too much installation progress and all this just to install the module , what we need is short way*" Bad news: there is no simple way; `cryptography` is not "just a module", it's a large complex library written in many different languages. But you can install the tools once in a temporary transient VM or a container, build `cryptography` wheel and distribute the wheel to all you hosts to be installed there without compilation.

Comment: "*do you mean to install the apk and then installing gcc musl-dev*" OMG, first you said it's RHEL 8.6, now you say Alpine, APK and musl. These are two different lines of Linux. You should indicate clearly what you want: is it RedHat with RPM and regular glibc, or Alpine with APK and MUSL libc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255364/discussion-between-judy-and-phd).

Comment: just to be clear we have only RHEL server with version 8.6 , if you can please post an answer with clearly instruction about ho w to install the module cryptography , I am little confuse here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Hat provides a pre-built version of Python `cryptography` module in the `python3-cryptography` RPM package. It is compatible with the system Python version 3.9. You can install it using:

```
yum install python3-cryptography
```

I believe it was already included in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6.